# PHPMyAdmin error code 500: "It seems that the connection to server has been lost" when exporting

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm running a new install of phpMyAdmin v4.7.5, on a web server at the IP address 10.0.0.10, and our MySQL server at 10.0.0.253. I'm able to browse our database tables without any issue, and literally everything else about phpMyAdmin is working.

Except exporting data from the database. Which is exactly what we need to do today.

The moment I click "Export" I get the following error message:

[image]

I'm at a loss for this one. There aren't any relevant errors in the Apache logs - just some debug information from ssl_engine_io.c and mod_authz_core.c

Comment: From the page header it looks like you are trying to export at the server level as I don't see the database name on the first line. Did you try to open this database then click on Export?

Comment: Yes, and the only thing different is that it takes a few seconds longer for the "Connection to the server has been lost" error to come up.

Comment: I used this particular page to show some of the settings of phpMyAdmin, plus the version and OS.

Comment: If you create another database with just one table and a few rows in it, does it work?

Comment: No. I have also tried doing this on a brand new database on localhost, logged into phpMyAdmin as root. So it's not some kind of firewall issue, nor is it an issue with any database I've tried to export.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE

Comment: I could use some help about how I can at least narrow the problem down for you. I'm out of ideas here.

Comment: An internal server error happens at the web server level, not at the phpMyAdmin level, so there should be something in Apache's error log. If not, I am also out of ideas.

Answer (score 6):

No Need to Increase **memory_limit** and **max_input_vars** from php.ini, Please follow below Steps  and Fixed phpmyadmin 500 error.

**Step 1**:- cd /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection

**Step 2**:- Find below line with ---> `grep -rin "newInstanceArgs"` in ContainerBuilder.php

```
$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
```

**Step 3** :- Please add  "array_values"  as like below mentioned. https://prnt.sc/1su27ef

old line :-

```
$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs($arguments);
```

new Line:-

```
$service = null === $r->getConstructor() ? $r->newInstance() : $r->newInstanceArgs(array_values($arguments));
```

**Step4** :-  Restart your **apache2/nginx**.
Go  to your browser and check, Phpmyadmin 500 error gone now!

Answer (score 4):

Increase **`upload_max_filesize`** and **`post_max_size`** from php.ini

Answer (score 4):

Increase **memory_limit** and **max_input_vars** from php.ini

hope it will work for you 
working for me

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin is based on php on your server so it is sometimes restricted by php settings on your server.
Issues like you had frequently happens when your PhpMyAdmin handles large data. Not only when exporting large data but filtering, selecting or sorting them.
Server error 500 means your server process has error so if your website server are based on Php , mysql and apache, one of them should caused the error.
To fix the issue, there are a few ways:

```
1. Use other tools like Sequel-pro (which is not a php application so you don't have issues related to php).
2. Use mysql command lines on your server to dump files.
3. Modify php.ini carefully to enable handling large data.
```

I recommend 1 or 2.